# Data partition in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

i am working on machine learning project for that need to divide data in training and test .
for that i have used caret package for data partition.
i tried the following code for partition but didnt worked , can anyone tell me what changes i have to make so i can solve and proceed further for same data.
Code i have tried

```
index <- reactive({

     createDataPartition(new$student, p = .80,
                                     list = FALSE,
                                     times = 1) 
 train10 <- renderTable({ new[index,]
     train10
 })
 test10 <-renderTable({ new[-index,]
 test10
 })
 })
```

Comment: I don't see where you create `index`. Anyway, you should assign the partition to `index`. Also, I'm not sure this question really relates to shiny, so maybe remove that tag.

Comment: its shiny syntax